# fancybox- не могу удалить значение кнопки close

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин, fancybox

```
$('.modal').fancybox({
        defaults: {
            btnTpl: {
                download:
                    '<a download data-fancybox-download class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--download" title="{{DOWNLOAD}}" href="javascript:;">' +
                    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.62 17.09V19H5.38v-1.91zm-2.97-6.96L17 11.45l-5 4.87-5-4.87 1.36-1.32 2.68 2.64V5h1.92v7.77z"/></svg>' +
                    "</a>",

                zoom:
                    '<button data-fancybox-zoom class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--zoom" title="{{ZOOM}}">' +
                    '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M18.7 17.3l-3-3a5.9 5.9 0 0 0-.6-7.6 5.9 5.9 0 0 0-8.4 0 5.9 5.9 0 0 0 0 8.4 5.9 5.9 0 0 0 7.7.7l3 3a1 1 0 0 0 1.3 0c.4-.5.4-1 0-1.5zM8.1 13.8a4 4 0 0 1 0-5.7 4 4 0 0 1 5.7 0 4 4 0 0 1 0 5.7 4 4 0 0 1-5.7 0z"/></svg>' +
                    "</button>",

                close: '<button data-fancybox-close class="fancybox-button fancybox-button--close" title="{{CLOSE}}">' + "</button>"
                }

            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: чтобы что-то удалить - нужно что-то установить

Comment: @qwabra по подробнее можно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в том что не правильно прописал селектор которому она была подключена. Надо добавлять $('.modal[data-fancybox]').fancybox({})